# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 77 invalid identifier '"ReportRequestTime"'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation
> error: error line 1 at position 77 invalid identifier
> '"ReportRequestTime"' data is loading into the warehouse.

Trying to change modification type to created.

Comment: Do you think you should share SQL/sample data ? Without looking at the patient and symptoms, barely saying the patient is sick wont help anyone. Will it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.